# ArcGIS SketchViewModel: how to set some of the Graphics can't be deleted, only modified?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

https://codepen.io/U_B_U/pen/YzeppyZ?editors=1001

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
        <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel"
      ], (
        Map,
        MapView,
        GraphicsLayer, SketchViewModel
      ) => {
        const n = 1000; // number of points
        const c = {x:-122, y:38};

        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 5,
          center: [c.x, c.y]
        });

        const random = (max_radius) => {
          const radius = max_radius * Math.random();
          const angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
          return [c.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius, c.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius];
        };
        
        var graphics = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          [x, y] = random(12);
          graphics.push({geometry: {type: "point", latitude: y, longitude: x}});
        }
        
        const layer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.add(layer);
        layer.addMany(graphics);
        
        let layerView;
        view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(lv){
          layerView = lv;
        });
        
        view.ui.add("select-by-rectangle", "top-left");
        const selectButton = document.getElementById("select-by-rectangle");

        // click event for the select by rectangle button
        selectButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          view.popup.close();
          sketchViewModel.create("rectangle");
        });
        
        const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
          view: view,
          layer: layer
        });
        
       sketchViewModel.on("create", async (event) => {
          if (event.state === "complete") {
            const extent = event.graphic.geometry.extent;
             const intersection = layer.graphics.filter((graphic) =>
              extent.intersects(graphic.geometry)
            );
            layer.removeMany(intersection)
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    <div
      id="select-by-rectangle"
      class="esri-widget esri-widget--button esri-widget esri-interactive"
      title="Select features by rectangle"
    >
      <span class="esri-icon-checkbox-unchecked"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to set that when `geometry.x>-14481681`, the selected Graphics can't be deleted.

```js
sketchViewModel.on("update", (event) => {
        console.log(event)
      if(event.graphics[0].geometry.x > -14481681 && event.aborted) {
        sketchViewModel.complete();
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `extent.intersects(graphic.geometry)` is true `&&` `graphic.geometry.x` is within your range for your filtering.

Did you mean -144.81681? For me the value -121.8846718062792 e.g. worked.

Like `extent.intersects(graphic.geometry) && graphic.geometry.x <= -121.8846718062792`

Comment: I don't know how to set it up now. What does extent.intersects(graphic.geometry) && graphic.geometry.x <= -121.8846718062792 mean?

Comment: It means that it is checking whether both expressions are true otherwise the graphic is not added at `const intersection = layer.graphics.filter((graphic) =>
              extent.intersects(graphic.geometry)
            );`

Comment: @ChristianLutz How would this help in preventing delete?

Comment: @TomazicM Because the filter function would only include features when there is an intersection and the x value is in the desired range - I changed the check from outside > to being inside <=.

Comment: @ChristianLutz But how do you prevent deleting graphic in `sketchViewModel` with this filter, but still enable modify?